# undefined method `alias_method_chain' in active record 3.2.18 without rails migration

Tags: activerecord, migration

This is my Rakefile

```
require 'bundler'
Bundler.setup
require 'active_record'
require 'sqlite3'
require 'yaml'
require 'logger'

task :migrate => :environment do
   ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate('db/migrate', ENV["VERSION"] ? ENV["VERSION"].to_i : nil )
end

task :environment do
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(YAML::load(File.open('config/database.yaml'))['development'])
  ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
end
```

When I execute the task I got this error:

```
rake aborted!
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@ta/gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/base.rb:2449: warning: already initialized constant Class::VALID_FIND_OPTIONS
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@ta/gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/base.rb:2449: warning: previous definition of VALID_FIND_OPTIONS was here
undefined method `alias_method_chain' for #<Class:0x00000001606340>
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@ta/gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/base.rb:2002:in `method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@ta/gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/validations.rb:387:in `block in included'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@ta/gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/validations.rb:386:in `class_eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@ta/gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/validations.rb:386:in `included'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@ta/gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/base.rb:3210:in `include'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@ta/gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/base.rb:3210:in `block in <module:ActiveRecord>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@ta/gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/base.rb:3208:in `class_eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@ta/gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/base.rb:3208:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@ta/gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/base.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/marco/desenv/technical_analysis/Rakefile:14:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@ta/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@ta/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
```

I had some debug and some test... **Then i moved to 3.2.13** version of active record, and all worked as expected. I didn't find any docs for 3.2.18 version...

I don't mind to use 3.2.13 version, but I got curious about that.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you were using ActiveRecord 2.3.18, not 3.2.18 (the latter of which does not exist, to my knowledge). ActiveRecord 2.3 is getting to be quite old, and I don't believe it's compatible with Ruby 2.0, which you're using.

But the central issue, I think, is that [in Rails 2.2-2.3](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Module/alias_method_chain), `alias_method_chain` was moved to the `ActiveSupport` module, before being moved back to `Module` in 3.0. You're not including `ActiveSupport` in your task, and I think that's what was causing the problem.

So I think a quick fix would be just to `require "active_support"`.

Comment: I have a similar problem.  (`undefined method 'alias_method_chain'`, with ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.8).  I've tried getting `alias_method_chain` to work in the interpreter, first using `require "rubygems"` and `require "active_support"`, with no success - still `undefined method`.  Messing around, found that trying `ActiveSupport.alias_method_chain :test1, :test2` with trivial methods `test1` and `test2` still fails, but gives a different error: `undefined method 'test1_with_test2' for module 'ActiveSupport'`.