# Rails server wont run and I get error with "Rails sever" command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby

I'm on windows 10 and i'm using microsoft sql server.
Here's the error I get in cmd when I run command "Rails server":

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    59: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
    58: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
    57: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
    56: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
    55: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    54: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    53: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    52: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    51: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    50: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    49: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    48: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
    47: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    46: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    45: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    44: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
    43: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
    42: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:145:in `block in perform'
    41: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
    40: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
    39: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
    38: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    37: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    36: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    35: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    34: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    33: from C:/Users/My Comp/RubyProjects/Project1/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    32: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
    31: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
    30: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
    29: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
    28: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
    27: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    26: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    25: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    24: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    23: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    22: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    21: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-2.3.8/lib/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    20: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
    19: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
    18: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
    17: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    16: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    15: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    14: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    13: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    12: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    11: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
    10: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
     9: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
     8: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
     7: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     6: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
     5: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     4: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
     3: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter/core_ext/active_record.rb:145:in `<top (required)>'
     2: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter/core_ext/active_record.rb:145:in `include'
     1: from D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter/core_ext/active_record.rb:12:in `included'
     D:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter/core_ext/active_record.rb:13:in `singleton class': undefined method `alias_method_chain' for #<Class:ActiveRecord::Base> (NoMethodError)
     Did you mean?  alias_method
```

Comment: This is the important part in all that I believe, at the very end of the error output it says:  `'singleton class': undefined method 'alias_method_chain' for #<Class:ActiveRecord::Base> (NoMethodError)
    Did you mean?  alias_method` .  Maybe this, or at least it is a start : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987761/undefined-method-alias-method-chain-in-active-record-3-2-18-without-rails-migr1

Comment: Its hard to assist you in troubleshooting if you don't share what you were last working on. With limited information to go on, please post your `schema.rb` file and all other relevant files you were working on right up to the point you got to this error.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because gem adapter for Rails 5x is to obsolete, you have to use this gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', '~> 5.1', '>= 5.1.6', this may help you.

I have fix this error on the linux system (Ubuntu) and must have gem 'tiny_tds' installed in the system.

if you have gem 'tiny_tds' error installation for linux you should look at this [medium_publish](https://medium.com/@praaveen/setting-up-ubuntu-with-rails-5-and-mssql-using-tiny-tds-and-activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-gem-75d0a7fe8601)

I hope this help you.